# Chrome Extensions won't install when using ExtensionInstallForcelist in HKCU

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, gpo

Here's the deal.  We are trying to install some Chrome extensions (version 47+) via GPO.  We're putting the ExtensionInstallForcelist under the user configuration, but it's not working.  The registry entry shows up, so the GPO works, but Chrome doesn't seem to be reading it to perform the install.

There is a slight catch.  We are running Websense Endpoint agent on our systems, which installs its own Chrome extension by adding a registry entry under the ExtensionInstallForcelist in HKLM.

When I look at the Chrome Policies, I see the ExtensionInstallForcelist enabled only for "Machine".

Does Chrome only accept one install list?  Either HKLM or HKCU with HKLM being the preferred?  At least that's the behavior that I'm seeing.

Any help or information would be appreciated.  All of the information that I've found on Chrome Extensions and GPO only list the Machine policy and don't really cover the User policy.

Thank you.

Comment: All while being joined to a domain?

Comment: Yes, this is on a Windows 7 PC that is a domain member.

Answer (score 2):

We had the exact same issue as you, with the Websense Endpoint trumping any GPO User level ExtensionInstallForcelist settings we put in place for a custom Chrome Extension.

This was the party line  I found from Chromium project regarding who wins in User vs Machine chrome policies:

*"Correct. We do not merge policy values, we just use the value read from the highest-priority source."*

(Taken from this person who had the same problem:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/wygwLDak6ZQ/NKurhHpdCgAJ )

Observationally, the Machine level is apparently the higher priority source. As such, we moved all the Chrome extensions settings to the **Computer Configuration** level of the GPO instead, this worked and installed our custom extension and all settings, however, this in turn prevented the Websense Endpoint from making it's ExtensionInstallForcelist registry entries and stopped it loading correctly.

So we ended up adding the Websense Extension details to the machine level GPO ForceInstallList as well:

**mkkjioebiampndpmidmadhpmgffdckhe;C:\Program Files\Websense\Websense Endpoint\dlpext.xml**

This is obviously not the best approach, as we now need to manage/keep an eye the Websense endpoint deployments via GPO, but it got things working for the subset of machines we needed to install the Chrome extension on.